# Weakly compact left multipliers

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

This is Exercise 3(a) on p. 157 in Takesaki's *Operator algebras*.

Let $A$ be a C*-algebra. Then each opeator $T_a\colon A\to A$ given by $T_ax = ax$ ($a\in A$) is [weakly compact](http://www.impan.pl/~tkoch/teaching/cbst_lecture_4.pdf) if and only if $A$ is an ideal of $A^{**}$, the universal enveloping von Neumann algebra.

Any hints how to solve it will be appreciated.